# Aggregate function on spark RDD of type RDD[String,Int,String]

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate, apache-spark-sql, rdd

We are trying to use aggregation function on RDD .
Where RDD is in the form of RDD[Strng,Int,String]

Given a List of elements as

```
List(("Amit1",45,"M"),("Amit2",43,"M"),("Amit3",28,"F"),("Amit4",33,"F"),("Amit5",18,"F")

Steps :-
val data = sc.parallelize(List(("Amit1",45,"M"),("Amit2",43,"M"),("Amit3",28,"F"),("Amit4",33,"F"),("Amit5",18,"F")))
val dataMap =  data.map(line => (line._1 , (line._2,line._3)))
dataMap.collect().foreach(println)
```

out put is :-

```
(Amit1,(45,M))
(Amit2,(43,M))
(Amit3,(28,F))
(Amit4,(33,F))
(Amit5,(18,F))
```

Now , what we was trying is use aggregateByKey because we need to group on student and then apply sum of age and also count of similar students
We used aggregateByKey  but not working .

we found the way :-

```
dataMap.aggregateByKey((0,0))((acc,value)=>(acc._1 +value._1,acc._2+1) ,(acc1,acc2)=>(acc1._1+acc2._1 , acc1._2 + acc2._2) ).collect()
```

output will be

```
res27: Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((Amit3,(28,1)), (Amit4,(33,1)), (Amit1,(63,2)), (Amit2,(43,1)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done without creating the `dataMap` that you have created

```
val data = sc.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("Amit1",45,"M"),("Amit2",43,"M"),("Amit3",28,"F"),("Amit4",33,"F"),("Amit5",18,"F")))
    println(data.count())
    println(data.map(_._2).sum())
```

If `dataMap` is necessary for your further implementation, use below code:

```
val dataMap =  data.map(line => (line._1 , (line._2,line._3)))
dataMap.collect().foreach(println)
println(dataMap.count())
println(dataMap.map(_._2._1).sum())
```

Comment: Thanks . But what we was trying is use aggregateByKey because we need to group on student and then apply sum of age and also count of similar students.... we modified the description .... We found the way to do this by below code :-                                       dataMap.aggregateByKey((0,0))((acc,value)=>(acc._1 +value._1,acc._2+1) ,(acc1,acc2)=>(acc1._1+acc2._1 , acc1._2 + acc2._2) ).collect()